# Dropbox API for Erlang

Tags: api, rest, erlang, dropbox

is there a good dropbox API for erlang ?
It is possible to use REST to work with dropbox.
Is there a good REST helper library for erlang ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang definately has its own HTTP client, but I haven't come across a client REST library, but it shouldn't be too hard to roll your own on top of the client. There isn't an SDK for Erlang but AFAIK all the dropbox API SDK's revolve around wrapping the REST API anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you still interested, I've been working on it, and here is result — https://github.com/StepanKuzmin/erlang-dropbox